# Combined search in sails js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I have game collection:

```
{
  "name": "Play RoadRash",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "icon": "image-md-two-thirds.png",
  "id": "6dc41c3fa0e7"
}
```

and platform collection:

```
{
  "name": "PlayStation",
  "version": "7",
  "icon": "playstation.jpg",
  "id": "55eaf322f1a16"
}
```

I'm trying to create a search query who searches in both collection based on name parameters. Does anyone have any idea how to search on multiple collection in sails waterline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've wrote a controller with full-text search within all models. All what it does is search within all models and their attributes by `q` parameter from request. Here is the full code of this controller:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = {
  index: function (req, res) {
    var models = [];

    if (!req.param('q')) {
      return res.badRequest(null, null, 'You should specify a "q" parameter!');
    }

    var q = req.param('q');

    if (req.param('model')) {
      var modelStr = req.param('model').toString().toLowerCase();

      if (!(modelStr in sails.models)) {
        return res.badRequest(null, null, 'Cannot find model: ' + modelStr);
      }

      models.push({name: modelStr, model: sails.models[modelStr]});
    } else {
      _.forEach(sails.models, function (model, modelStr) {
        models.push({name: modelStr, model: model});
      });
    }

    Promise.map(models, function (modelObj) {
      var model = modelObj.model;
      var modelStr = modelObj.name;
      var where = _.transform(model.definition, function (result, val, key) {
        result.or.push(_.set({}, key, {contains: q}));
      }, {or: []});

      return model
        .find(where)
        .then(function (queryRes) {
          var resObj = {};
          resObj[modelStr] = queryRes;
          return Promise.resolve(resObj)
        });
    })
      .then(function (searchRes) {
        return _.transform(searchRes, function (result, val) {
          result = _.merge(result, val);
        }, {});
      })
      .then(res.ok)
      .catch(res.serverError)
  }
};
```

You can just copy-paste it in your `api/controllers/SearchController.js` and that's it. It still need to refactor this code, but it works.

Comment: How can i specify model name and parameters to search instead of searching in all model and in all keys.

Comment: I've updated answer with `model` parameter from response. So you can specify in what model you want to search.